# Windows status bar font and quick launch icon size wrong

Tags: windows-10, statusbar

My colleague's computer (Windows 10) is showing weird sizing effects for multiple parts of Windows. As seen in the image, the Explorer status bar font is too large, and the Quick Launch icons are too large. In addition, some pop up menus have massive text, and likely related Word's document navigation pane text is too large.

This problem only occurs on the one user profile. Other users of the PC don't have the problem.

It's not due to icon scaling settings or resolution settings. Changing these through the normal Windows settings options doesn't fix the issue.

Is there a way to fix these graphical/font size issues?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try Settings / Ease of Access / Display - Make text bigger and drag it to the lef.

Also try Settings / Ease of Access / Magnifier - Change the zoom level to 100%. And if it is not neede, turn off Magnifier.

Change icon size in Quick Launch - unlock Quick Launch if it is not already unlocked. Right click anywhere on task bar / Taskbars and uncheck Quick Launch. Add new Taskbar (should point you back to QuickLaunch), add it. Change icon size by clicking right within Quick Launch and view / small icons.

If it does not help, change back to big and again to small. Restart PC - that should help (it did on mine).

If there is still no effect, restart PC anyway.